# When i try to print the mean and standard deviation, I am prompted with a name error: variable not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to print the mean and standard deviation however in its current form it doesnt recognize anything inside the loop. How would I go about correcting this to properly display what is intended. When i try to print the mean it says ex not defined.

```
import numpy as np
p = 0.44
q = 0.56
mu_1 = 26.5
sigma = 4.3
mu_2 = 76.4

n = 7
print( 'total number of jobs =', n)
lst_times = []
j = 0
def calc_avg_std(n):
    while j < 100:
        m = np.random.binomial(n,p)
        easy_jobs = np.random.normal(mu_1,sigma,m)
        n_chall = n-m
        chall_jobs = np.random.exponential(mu_2,n_chall)
        totalTime = sum(easy_jobs) + sum(chall_jobs)
        lst_times.append(totalTime)
        j = j + 1
        ex = (mu_1 * p) + (mu_2 * q)
        ex2 = (p *((mu_1**2)))+ (q*(mu_2**2)*2)
        var = ex2-(ex**2)
        stdev = np.sqrt(var)
    return [ex , stdev] 
print(' mean is',ex)
```

I tried this code without the def and return and runs properly but the professor insists that it should be implemented.

Comment: Walk through your code line by line. How is `ex` defined, and how does the code flow get to that point. Do that, and you will find that you never reach that line. Look back at your notes for how to use functions.

Answer (score 0):

**def** is used to create a function. When you use **return** you return the values to the caller.

Replace your last prin witht the following lines:

- call the function and keep the return values
- print the returned values

```
mean, stdev = calc_avg_std(n)
print(mean)
```